# Cannot open shadow copy of deleted files

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, data-recovery, file-corruption

I accidentally "permanently" deleted a folder from my C drive. I can see two shadow copies of the deleted folder in Shadow Explorer and was able to export the folder to an external drive, however, I cannot open any of the files in that folder, e.g.

- If I try to open a PDF, I get the error: `Adobe Acrobat reader could not open '[filename].pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded).`:

[image]

- If I try to open an MP4, I get the error: `Can't play. Choose something else to play. This item is in a format we don't support.. 0xc1010103`

[image]

**Why might this be happening and is there anything I could do to repair the files?**

I did not save anything to the drive after the deletion, but did continue to use the computer in order to install Windows File Recovery, Shadow Explorer, Recuva, and also rebooted the computer in order to run `Chkdsk`. **Could this have caused the deleted files to be overwritten?**

Also, I could not see any of the deleted files in Recuva scan results, even after enabling the "Deep Scan" option.

Here are the `Chkdsk` logs:

[image]

Comment: What folder? Shadow Explorer views the contents of Windows' built in recovery tool, Volume Shadow Copy. You should be able to restore the folder using Last Known Good Configuration or System Restore points.

Comment: Thanks @music2myear, how do I use Last Known Good Configuration or System Restore points? The deleted folder was in `C:\Users\user\Documents\`, but when I right-click on the Documents folder and select Restore previous versions, the version history is empty.

Comment: Without real backup, your chances don't seem very good.

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, I thought as much. Frustratingly, backup is disabled by default on Windows. Would you know why the files are still visible in Shadow Explorer but unreadable? Funnily enough, the files I deleted intentionally six months ago are still sitting in the Recycle Bin, but not the ones I deleted today by mistake. Cue Ironic by Alanis Morissette.

Comment: There is no replacement for manual backups - counting on Windows is taking a chance.